# InvalidFormatException while deserializing parameterized url to a java.net.URI through Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a uri in the following format in a json document

```
https://xyz.com/index.php?SCR=visa&restaurant_id=2322&location={LOCATIONID}&customer={CUSTOMERID}&tab={TABID}&
```

I am using fasterxml Jackson ObjectMapper to deserialize this url to an java.net.URI (json spec has format="uri")

But I get the following exception

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.net.URI from String value 'https://eat24hours.com/index.php?SCR=m_paypal&restaurant_id=21696&location={LOCATIONID}&customer={CUSTOMERID}&tab={TABID}&': not a valid textual representation a
```

Is there a DeserializationFeature or module which can handle such parameterized urls

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson can deserialize a `URI` just fine, but your URI is invalid.

```
https://xyz.com/index.php?SCR=visa&restaurant_id=2322&location={LOCATIONID}&customer={CUSTOMERID}&tab={TABID}&
                                                               ^          ^ invalid characters
```

This seems to be a template for a URI where you haven't replaced the `{...}`  placeholders. Either change your field to `String`, write your own deserializer that fills in the spots, or make it a valid URI.

Answer (score 1):

That's coming from the URI class itself. Jackson can't do anything with that. You'll need to use a `String` instead of `URI`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I looked up on URI Specs .As per IPV6 I can use '[' ']' chars as they are reserver while '{' is a part of '}' excluded characters.Does any one know what is '[' reserved for ']' http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt